# Davinci Resolve not Starting (Aborted (core dumped))

Tags: drivers, software-installation, intel

I've installed Davinci Resolve 16 with the help of the Linux Installer. When  I start the program nothing happens. So I decided to check the log output.
Hence when i run

```
/opt/resolve/bin/resolve
```

which starts resolve, I get this output:

```
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
16.1.2 (#026) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: 15914C40
[0x7f9315914c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-01-09 22:15:54,182 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0x7f9315914c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-01-09 22:15:54,182 | Loaded log config from /home/flolu/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7f9315914c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2020-01-09 22:15:54,182 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Maybe the issue occurs because I don't have a NVIDIA GPU (I have Intel Iris Plus Graphics). On my other machine with NVIDIA GPU it's working fine.

Maybe I need to install a driver for Intel Graphics?

My system:

[image: system]

Comment: I'm betting that the NVIDIA support and testing for DR + Linux is more robust and mature than for Intel.  But I haven't tried your combination.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for what I could try to fix it?

Comment: Get an NVIDIA GPU!

Comment: Yeah I have a NVIDIA GPU in my workstation, where it works fine. But I also want to use Resolve on my notebook :)

Comment: Resolve is sort of notorious for crashing a lot.  I think their capacity and/or commitment to thorough testing is a real challenge... in fairness, it's being given away and the range of target platforms supported is huge.  It's an enormous investment to be stable on all those targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DaVinci Resolve requires an NVIDIA graphics card on Linux and the original NVIDIA drivers. Nouveau drivers aren't supported. It won't run on your hardware.

Resolve runs fine on Ubuntu, but you'll also need to install the dependencies yourself. [Here is a good HowTo](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/how-to-install-davinci-resolve-15-in.html) for doing so.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same message, but I have the latest (440) NVIDIA driver working.  The strange thing is, the program ran the last time I used it but now will no longer run!

Comment: Did you get a Kernel update? Run `nvidia-detector` and `dpkg-query -l nvidia*|grep ii`. Do both show the same version (currently 440 for me)? Try to boot the previous kernel version. Currently 5.3.0-51 seems to work, but 5.3.0-53 doesn't.

Comment: i think something got hosed up in CL... an update and a reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

DaVinci Resolve requires CentOS or RHEL 7+. Ubuntu or other distributions are not supported.

Comment: Offically not. But  @fluka wrote on an other computer it is running.